# How to center text under math symbols

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

I was looking for a way to center text underneath math symbols such as constraints or regions. More specifically, from vector calculus, if we were to have a double integral bounded by some region D, then we would have the two integral signs with a D underneath. It looks like the D_1 and D_2 as seen below.

[image: Double Integral over General Region D]

Comment: I leave this to the math-experts here, but it sounds after a job of `\stackrel[below]{main}{above}` (`stackrel` package) in the general case and a simple `\iint_{D}` or `\iint\limits_{D}` for the double integral (with the `amsmath` package).

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. The `\iint\limits_{D}` did the trick. It was the `\limits` I believe that was needed. I have a question about the `\stackrel[below]{main}{above}`, what type of text or math code would actually goes in the "below" ,"main", and "above" fields?

Comment: about `\stackrel`: Most likely any math code as well as text inside `\mbox{..}` or better `\text{..}`.

Comment: @Martin: with all respect due to Heiko Oberdiek, I don't think that `\stackrel` or `\stackbin` are *the* answer (they build relations and binary operations). First of all one should consider `\overset` and `\underset` from **amsmath** (which already do a good job of recognizing automatically the math kind of the main object).

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, as stated above I'm not an expert with math. The `\stack...` just sounded good for this case. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cannot see this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ \iint\limits_{D_1} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}A \] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbet: What do you mean by you cannot see the code? The output?

Comment: @night owl: I cannot see that the D1 is not centered below the double integral